# JTable with different color value

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable

I want to display data in a `JTable` like in the picture bellow:

[image]

It can be observed that in the second row appear only 3 values, which I want to be colored. Also I have a problem in dispaying those rows, with the indentation. My disply so far looks like this:[image]

I would like to fix the propblem with the indentation and remove th `,`.

My code:

```
leftList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                ArrayList<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

                if(!event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    int proteinIndex = leftList.getSelectedIndex();

                            Object rowData[][] = { {codes}, {values} };
                            Object columnNames[] = {codes};
                            JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
                            table.setTableHeader(null);
                            table.setShowGrid(false);
                            tablePane = new JScrollPane(table);
                            tablePane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(765,40));
                            rightPanel.removeAll();
                            rightPanel.updateUI();
                            rightPanel.add(tablePane);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void showGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(leftPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(listScrollPane,BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(rightPanel);
        frame.setTitle("GUI");
        frame.setSize(1000,500);
        frame.setLocation(200,100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Can you please help me achieve a result like in the first picture?

Comment: You will need a custom `TableCellRenderer` which maintains the rules about how values get colored.  You may want to separate the logic for these decisions though

Comment: Don't ever call `updateUI` unless you are changing the look and feel of the UI, it's very inefficient.  Instead of creating a new `JTable` each time, simply create a single `JTable` and update it's model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It can be observed that in the second row appear only 3 values, which I want to be colored.

You will have to create a custom [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) that colors each cell corresponding to the item in that cell. But...

> I would like to fix the propblem with the indentation and remove th ,.

The items within the `List` are not placed individually in a table cell. Rather, the call...

```
Object rowData[][] = { {codes}, {values} };
```

...uses the `toString` method of `ArrayList`, resulting in a table with 2 rows and 1 column. An alternative approach to get each item of the `List` into it's own table cell is to convert the `List` to arrays

```
Object rowData[][] = { codes.toArray(), values.toArray() };
Object columnNames[] = codes.toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixed the problem with the indentation. Now I am trying to color the values.